# How to store superscript in XML attribute and read using XSL?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, superscript

I have a requirement where I need create an XML document dynamically. Some of the attributes of the nodes of this XML contain superscript Reg etc. My question is how should I store such superscript characters in XML and then read it using XSL to render as HTML. A sample XML is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<node name="Some text <sup>®</sup>"/>
```

I know this cannot be stored under sup tag inside attribute as it breaks XML. I tried using `&lt;sup&gt;` also in place of opening and closing tag. But then they are rendered as `<sup>` on HTML instead of actually making it superscript. 
Please let me know the solution for this problem. I have control over generation of XML. I can write it the correct way, If I know what is the right way to store superscripts.

Comment: Found solution. In XML I am saving it as '&lt;sup&gt;&amp;reg;&lt;/sup&gt;' and reading it as '<xsl:value-of select="$myVariable1" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>'

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using XSL to transform the input into HTML, I would suggest using a different method to encode the fact that some things need to be superscripts.  Make up your own simple markup, for example

```
<node name="Some text [[®]]"/>
```

The markup can be anything that you can uniquely identify later and doesn't occur naturally in your data. Then in your XSL process the attribute values that can contain this markup with a custom template that converts the special markup to `<sup>` and `</sup>`.  This allows you to keep the document structure (i.e. not move these string values to text nodes) and still achieve your goal.

Comment: can you share some sample xsl to convert this custom markup to '<sup>'

Answer (score 1):

> Please let me know the solution for this problem. I have control over
>   generation of XML. I can write it the correct way, If I know what is
>   the right way to store superscripts.

**Because attributes can only contain values (no nodes), the solution is to store markup (nodes) inside elements**:

```
<node>
 <name>Some text <sup>®</sup></name>
</node>
```

Comment: I cannot convert the attribute to a new element. When I say I have control over XML generation, I mean on how I enter values to attributes.

Comment: @user1314871, Then you have our sympathy. I wouldn't recommend inventing a new, complicated and unnecessary language for imitating markup inside an attribute. This is abuse and this clearly is *not* XML. I strongly recommend the creation of a (possibly entirely new) XML document that is as simple and as readable as possible. In case you are constrained to do this, then just *not* use XML.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only single characters like ® that need to be made superscript, then you can leave the XML without crooks like `<sup>`, i.e. like

```
<node name="Some text ®"/>
```

and look for the to-be-superscripted characters during processing. A template like this might help:

```
<xsl:template match="node/@name">
  <xsl:param name="nameString" select="string()"/>
  <!-- We're stepping through the string character by character -->
  <xsl:variable name="firstChar" select="substring($nameString,1,1)"/>

  <xsl:choose>
    <!-- '®' can be extended to be a longer string of single characters
         that are meant to be turned into superscript -->
    <xsl:when test="contains('®',$firstChar)">
      <sup><xsl:value-of select="$firstChar"/></sup>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$firstChar"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>

  <!-- If we we didn't yet step through the whole string,
       chop off the first character and recurse. -->
  <xsl:if test="$firstChar!=''">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
      <xsl:with-param name="nameString" select="substring($nameString,2)"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

This approach is however not very efficient, especially if you have lots of `name` attributes and/or very long `name` attributes. If your application is performance critical, then better do some testing whether the impact on processing times is justifiable.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that @DimitreNovatchev can come up with more efficient ideas. Taking advantage of some XSLT 2.0 features, there might be room for improvement.

Comment: While I know a few aways this could be done, I would strongly discourage anyone from misusing XML.

Comment: What about the solution that Jim mentioned. That sounds good at first look. You guys have any comments on that?

Comment: @RossCooper: Of course that's possible as well. I'd consider my approach to be less misuse of XML (in Dimitre's sense), as the styling (superscript) is achieved exclusively by the stylesheet (isn't styling one of a stylesheet's core tasks?). Of course, if you need to be able to make arbitrary character sequences superscript, something along the lines of Jim Garrisson's approach is inevitable. On the other hand, if you have to fear that there might potentially occur names that will contain the sequence "[[", you're screwed again...

Comment: Please consider the other side of the problem as well. When I am able to take <sup> to html by doing &lt;sup&gt; its getting rendered as it is. Browser is not parsing it as html tag but as normal text. What's the solution for that?